# Cannot read propert of undefined

Tags: javascript

I was using the "this" keyword here in my code and decided to replace that with squares[i]. As I click the div, my console is showing me error message: "Cannot read propery of undefined".

```
var colors=[
"rgb(255, 0, 0)",
"rgb(255, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 0)" ,
"rgb(0, 255, 255)",
"rgb(0, 0, 255)",
"rgb(255, 0, 255)" ];

var squares=document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor=colors[3];
var display=document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
display.textContent=pickedColor;

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
//ADD INITIAL COLORS TO SQUARES
squares[i].style.backgroundColor=colors[i];
//ADD EVENTLISTENERS TO SQUARES
squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(squares[i].style.backgroundColor);
 });
}

//__________________________________________________________________________
//This is the correct version of the code
 var colors=[
"rgb(255, 0, 0)",
"rgb(255, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 0)" ,
"rgb(0, 255, 255)",
"rgb(0, 0, 255)",
"rgb(255, 0, 255)" ];

var squares=document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor=colors[3];
var display=document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
display.textContent=pickedColor;

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){

//ADD INITIAL COLORS TO SQUARES
squares[i].style.backgroundColor=colors[i];
//ADD EVENTLISTENERS TO SQUARES
squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(this.style.backgroundColor);
 });
}
```

I have added two versions of the code. The first one is incorrect, while the second one is the correct one.

Comment: What is the value of `squares.length`?

Comment: Show us before and after. The provided code snippet does not give clear context

Comment: You nead to learn about [Javascript Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).  The `i` in your event listener function will always be set to `squares.length`, which is outside of the index

Comment: squares[i].length= 6

Comment: `i === squares.length` when your loop completes, which is before any click handlers are called, so inside your click handler you're accessing `squares[squares.length]` which is undefined.

Comment: Perhaps i is out of scope in the event listener function?

Comment: Still dont get it :(

Comment: @Usama Add `console.log( i, squares[i] );` after your loop, and consider that the log runs before you every click on anything. Then when you click on something, it's no different. Put `console.log( i, squares[i] );` inside your click event listener too.

Comment: @Usama After doing that you will understand the problem, then read the linked duplicate to learn about various solutions. My favourite that works in modern browsers but not some very old browsers, is to just change `var i=0` to `let i=0`.